# Unable to run R from command line (in Ubuntu)

Tags: r, anaconda

Recently I installed Anaconda to open R in iPython/jupyter notebook.

Now, I can't run R from command line, when I type R i get:

```
$> R
/home/aknirala/anaconda3/lib/R/bin/exec/R: error while loading shared libraries: libreadline.so.6: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I can still open it by searching in application though. My questions:

1. How can I know from where R is being run when I search it via application.
2. Is there any easy fix to run R from anaconda? (I get the same error when I try to run R from iPython notebook).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realized that Anaconda has added some script at the end of ~/.bashrc

Removing that, fixed it.